# What was the first manga magazine?

Tags: manga-production, manga-history

What was the first manga magazine? And what manga are published in there? I'm curious about this, I'm only familiar with Shonen Jump and it [published in Japan by Shueisha from 1970](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monthly_Sh%C5%8Dnen_Jump)

I was wondering if there are any other manga magazines that have been published before Shonen Jump?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few manga magazines that started before Shonen Jump. Going off of [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_manga_magazines), the earliest published manga magazine was Monthly Manga Shounen (Gekkan Manga Shounen), which started in 1947.

There are manga magazine publishing companies that predate 1947, such as [Shogakukan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogakukan), which was founded in 1922; [Kodansha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodansha), which was formally founded in 1938; and [Kadokawa Shoten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadokawa_Shoten), which was founded in 1945. As far as I can tell, though, none of these companies published manga magazines before 1947.

[Toward the Terra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toward_the_terra) was one manga published in Monthly Manga Shounen.