# Who started the format 18-36 pages in weekly and 36-60 pages in monthly manga magazine?

Tags: manga-history

There are a bunch of manga magazines like:

**Weekly**

- [Weekly Shonen Jump](http://www.shonenjump.com/j/)
- [Weekly Shonen Sunday](http://websunday.net/)
- [Weekly Shonen Magazine](http://www.shonenmagazine.com/)
- **and many more**

**Monthly**

- [Monthly Urasunday](http://urasunday.com/)
- [Ultra Jump](http://ultra.shueisha.co.jp/)
- **and many more**

There is a different of the total amount of page for every series that published in each of manga magazine in japan every week/month. The total amount of page  for weekly serialization, has about 18-20 pages for a one chapter each week. For a monthly magazine, they have around 30-50 pages each month.

According that, what started this format to be a common in a manga industry?  I mean, since when this a mount of page for weekly/monthly manga magazine used ?

Additional info : There is already a question that similar with this kind of topic, but it didn't answer my question

Related Topic : [What was the first manga magazine?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6708/what-was-the-first-manga-magazine)

Comment: Could it be as simple as the amount of quality pages a person can produce in a given time span?

Comment: @VDWWD but when i see the [this](https://imgur.com/FsceQO2), i think 18-36 pages per week is too hard for a person to work like that

Comment: Have you seen [Bakuman](https://myanimelist.net/anime/7674/Bakuman)? In there they use assistants to do the extra stuff like Beta and applying tones. I know that it's not a real world example but having one or 2 would significantly lower the work load for the author and maybe that is how they are able to produce 36 pages?